# Sitecore 8 MVC ajax call route register

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, custom-routes, sitecore8.1

I come with a problem caused by the poor sitecore documentation and my small experience.

The case:
I have a sitecore project which was not set up by me, but I had to develop over it. It's nothing complicated, few renderings - basic stuff

Issue:
I have to add 3 custom routes to use them with some ajax calls. I have the routeconfig.cs file and I added those routes here, but it looks like this is not executed because there is no Global Class anywhere.

So, because I read that I should use those pipelines but I don't exactly understand how to use one that's executed only once, when the app starts

I have one developed by someone else which handles the 404, but this one is executed on each request. I don't want to check if the route exists and register it on this process

Is there any other way ?

This is how it works now:

```
namespace SS.Configuration.Pipelines
{
    public class Custom404ResolverPipeline : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

            if (RouteTable.Routes["AjaxCall"] == null) RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            //do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

You should register your routes in the `initialize` pipeline so that they are only registered once on application start up: [How to register custom ASP.NET MVC routes in Sitecore](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/700677)

Example from the linked article:

Create a custom processor for the initialize pipeline and define custom route in the Process method similar to the following:

```
public class RegisterCustomRoute
{
  public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
  {
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute", "some/route/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
  }
}
```

Add this processor to the initialize pipeline right before the Sitecore InitializeRoutes processor. You can do this with the help of the configuration patch file in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="MyNamespace.RegisterCustomRoute, MyAssembly"  patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </initialize>‌
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've been to this link too :-) All good but when I test it I get this: Could not get pipeline: preprocessRequest (domain: )

Comment: I think the problem is that in my sitecore.config, this one is missing Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes Is this normal ?

Comment: That's not normal for a clean Sitecore install, the `InitializeRoutes` processor is defined in `Sitecore.Mvc.config`, check it exists and there isn't another config that removes this. You can browse to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` to see the final merged Sitecore config.

Comment: Waaait ! I didn't know that there is Sitecore.Mvc.config - check question description:  little experience - The processor is there, but, why do I get that error then ? Could not get pipeline: preprocessRequest (domain: )]
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +269

Comment: if anyone gets stuck with the same - there is some problem with copying-pasting into config files from @jammykam's answer above. So just take any Sitecore config as an example and manually type in the text from jammykam's answer :)

Comment: @KateButenko https://www.gitbook.com/cover/book/tra38/essential-copying-and-pasting-from-stack-overflow.jpg?build=1481432910027

Comment: @jammykam always actual! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to go by pipelines way, you can also download web activator package from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/) and then implement kind of Startup Class to Register your routes.

```
[assembly: PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SomeNameSpace.StartUp), "Start")]

namespace SomeNameSpace
{

public static class StartUp
{
    public static void Start()
    {

        MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     }
 }
}
```

and in your Register routes method of RouteConfig class you can map your route as below

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute", "some/route/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
```